# How to add custom error page to app served with shinyproxy

Tags: shinyproxy

I am serving a R app using ShinyProxy with default configurations. When there is an error, the default error page exposes a lot of information about what caused the error. I would like to replace the error page, but cannot figure out where to find the HTML that creates the error message.

There is a git repo https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-config-examples/tree/master/04-custom-html-template shows how to change html for log in and the index page, but i cannot seem to find the error- does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/adding-404-page-in-express
and you can replace `res.send('<h1> Page not found </h1>');` with `res.sendFile(pagedir);`